# Why can't I use atoll while using cygwin

Tags: c++, c++11, cygwin

I'm using cygwin and trying to compile a file with the following command.

```
$g++ -std=c++0x test.cpp -o test
```

But cygwin tells me that atoll undefined. Then I google a little bit and found out that it is cygwin's problem.

Some of the sites says that I can set something to disable the -ansi-std=c98 effect, but I don't understand how to do that.

Can someone explain to me what can I do in order to fix the problem?

I will put a website I found(Others are written in Chinese):
[disable effect of -ansi -std=c89 on system include files](http://www.nntp.perl.org/group/perl.perl5.porters/2007/02/msg120546.html)

But I can't understand what his solution is talking about ><

## Dream Target:

I wonder if there is a way to get rid of this problem and don't need to undefine things everytime. That will be great if I can no longer deal with that problem.

Thank you all who are willing to spend time on this strange problem^^

Comment: If you googled and found a helpful page, please include the link in your question.

Comment: Why use `atoll` anyway? It returns 0 on failure and can therefore not distinguish between, say, "0" and "x". It's only reliable if you already know that the input is a valid number, or if 0 is not allowed.

Comment: In particular, the equivalent function that doesn't suffer the problems Christian mentioned is [`strtoll`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strtoll)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a problem in the header files. A patch might not be too terribly difficult, but a (possibly) easier solution for you is to undefine `__STRICT_ANSI__` on the compile line.

```
g++ -std=c++0x -U__STRICT_ANSI__ test.cpp -o test
```

That works for me with @R Sahu's test code for both `-std=c++0x` and `-std=c++11`.

Actually, I think I'm wrong. I think Cygwin is right. `atoll` isn't `__STRICT_ANSI__`. So, if you want to use it, the above is the best way.

Answer (score 0):

I tested with the following code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
   std::cout << atoll(argv[1]) << std::endl;
}
```

What worked for me:

```
g++  test-130.cc   -o test-130
```

What did not work for me:

```
g++  -std=c++0x test-130.cc   -o test-130
g++  -std=c++11 test-130.cc   -o test-130
```

Comment: Me too. The biggest problem is I have to edit Makefile to make it work and that is what I don't want to do.